# Removing Null Island Coordinate

Tags: ios, google-maps, null

I'm using Google Maps GMSMutablePath to create a large polygon to highlight a route with a variable width polygon.

I seem to get the Null Island coordinate from time to time. What is the proper way to filter or exclude that coordinate from GMSMutablePath? Is it a coordinate that is 0,0 or null, null, etc...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the object actually a CLLocationCoordinate2D?

Answer (score -1):

The Google Maps iOS API uses CLLocationCoordinate2D in the GMSMutablePath.

You can use the CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid to exclude null island and other improperly formatted coordinates.

```
if (CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(myCoordinate)) {
NSLog(@"Coordinate valid");
} else {
NSLog(@"Coordinate invalid");
}
```

Comment: `CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(CLLocation().coordinate)` returns `true`.